# trying to save an image with its name intact php

Tags: php

Hi i am using the script below to save an image FROM another domain into my own domain.

```
  //get image name and extension
  $img = 'http://otherdomain.com/image/123.jpg';
  $getname = explode('/', $img);
  $thumbname = $getname[count($getname) - 1];
  //save the image file
  $file = file_get_contents($img);
  $path = 'thumbs/'+ $thumbname;
  file_put_contents($path, $file);
```

But i cant get this to work. the $path resulted in `123` but not `123.jpg`(which i need).
and am i doing the file get content and file put content right?

Comment: Maybe you are using Window with option "Hide known file extension". Your script is totally fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `basename()` to determine the last part (= filename) of a path.

```
$image_name = basename($img); // This will contain 123.jpg
```

See the docs over at http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: Though good advice, it's not what's 'wrong' with his script.  His exploding will technically provide the file name correctly with the given URL.  The problem is that he tried to use + as concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use http://php.net/parse_url.

And `+` is addition in PHP, not concatenation.  Change it to a `.`

```
$path = 'thumbs/' . $thumbname;
```